# Appending characters to a List string

Tags: c#, list, append

I have an optional custom prefix and suffix in my application, that I want to add to each of the items in my string List.  I have tried all of the following and none are working.  Can someone point me in the right direction please?

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>{ "dog", "cat", "pig", "bird" };

string prefix = "my ";
string suffix = " sucks!";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(suffix);
sb.Insert(0, prefix);
MyList = sb.ToString();  //This gives me red squigglies under sb.ToString();
```

I also tried:

```
myList = myList.Join(x => prefix + x + suffix).ToList();  //Red squigglies
```

and:

```
sortBox1.Join(prefix + sortBox1 + suffix).ToList();  //Red squigglies
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's not really clear why you're using a `StringBuilder` at all here, or why you'd be trying to do a join. It sounds like you want:

```
var suckingList = myList.Select(x => "my " + x + " sucks")
                        .ToList();
```

This is the absolutely normal way of performing a projection to each item in a list using LINQ.

Comment: Worekd great, Jon.  Thanks.  How would I go about making the prefix = "?  obviously 'prefix = """;' doesnt work.

Comment: @Jeagr: You'd just escape it: `"\"" + x`

Comment: @Jeagr: It already is. http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/02/17/c-in-depth-2nd-edition-now-available-in-mobi-epub-kindle-format.aspx

Comment: Could also use `$"my {x} sucks"` in the expression for better readability

Comment: @ageroh: You could now - but this answer was written in 2012. I'm not going to go over all the answers I wrote before C# 6 came out just to introduce string interpolation...

Answer (score 2):

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>{ "dog", "cat", "pig", "bird" };
List<string> myNewList = new List<string>();

string prefix = "my ";
string suffix = " sucks!";

foreach(string s in myList)
{
     myNewList.Add(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", prefix, s, suffix);
}
```

myNewList now contains the correct data.

Comment: LINQ is a much simpler approach - and there's no point in using `string.Format` when you're just concatenating three strings. (Oh, and change `add` and `format` to have capitals letters...)

Comment: Was just thinking about the string.Format and wether it's needed. Tened to use it as a default anyway. I figured the foreach was more descriptive but your right LINQ is more succinct

Comment: @TimSchmelter: But that's not what's going on here - it's *just* concatenating them all. I view `string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", prefix, s, suffix` here as less readable than just straight `prefix + s + suffix`.