# append html tag as prefix and suffix to list of strings

Tags: c#, list, append

I am trying to add `html <li>` tag as prefix and suffix to each element of list of strings.

Here is the list of string :

```
IList<string> lstUniversities = new List<string>();

lstUniversities.Add("<sup>1</sup>Harward University, USA");

lstUniversities.Add("<sup>2</sup>Yale University, USA");

lstUniversities.Select(u => "<li> " + u + " </li>").ToList();
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<li><sup>1</sup>Harward University, USA</li>

<li><sup>2</sup>Yale University , USA</li>
```

May I know why the `html <li>` tag is not appended ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because [`Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a new collection of type `IEnumerable<T>`, it does not modify the existing one. so, you need to refer to that new one which `.Select(u => "<li> " + u + " </li>").ToList();` returns like:

```
lstUniversities = lstUniversities.Select(u => "<li> " + u + " </li>").ToList();
```

Now we are assigning the new collection to out `lstUniversities` variable and we should see the expected output.

Alternatively use a `foreach` or `for` loop to do that:

```
for(int i=o; i < lstUniversities.Count; i++)
       lstUniversities[i] = "<li> " + lstUniversities[i] + " </li>";
```

or with [ForEach()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
lstUniversities.ForEach(u  => { u  = "<li> " + u   + " </li>"; });
```

Comment: @stom can you explain more, what you mean by didn't worked, and i am just amazed you challenged **Jon Skeet's** answer :D

Comment: can you update your question with what your code now looks like after updating it as suggested?

Comment: @TimSchmelter of-course but that would be too much for a beginner, it obviously returns `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Jon Skeet's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13932024/2218697) , works fine, I made small typo while checking the code. I have done this before but missed this time. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using a stringbuilder. Not expansive and results in very readable code, and leaves your input list clean.

```
   var stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (var item in lstUniversities)
                    {
                        stringbuilder.Append("<li>");
                        //stringbuilder.Add("<sup>1</sup>Harward University, USA");
                        stringbuilder.Append(item);
                        stringbuilder.Append("</li>");
                    }
```